# Relyance of plate distance on the capacitor equation

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, voltage, distance

I am studying capacitors and i cannot seem to understand why the increase/ decrease in voltage and distance between the plates would affect the capacitor's abillity to store charge. Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the 'ability to store charge' involved.  What is different,
is the proportional relationship between stored energy per unit charge (voltage)
and amount of charge (ampere-seconds) stored.   A rechargeable battery
keeps its charge chemically bonded (and stores a LOT of charge for a given
voltage rise), while a close-spaced-plate capacitor stores charge near
a metal plate which is equivalent to storing it near an equal
and opposite "image charge".   The bonding of the stored charge to that image
charge is less than the chemical bonding, but it's more than if that 
second plate was absent.

In static electricity experiments, it is easy to see that a grounded object B
brought near a charged object A gets an induced surface charge: if you
remove the ground, then pull B away from A, the voltage on B goes up.
Now consider a carpet to be object A, and your plastic shoe sole as object
B: this is how you get an electric shock in dry weather.

The important thing is, pulling B away from A doesn't change the charge on B: it
only changes the capacitance, i.e. the charge divided by the voltage.  So,
the voltage rises.